# how to access parent value from child json object?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Let's say I have a users collection in Firebase which follows the following format:

- Users

  - 11

    - FirstName:"John"
    - LastName:"Smith"
    - EmailAddress:"jsmith@gmail.com"
  - 22

    - FirstName:"Bill"
    - LastName:"Jones"
    - EmailAddress:"bjones@gmail.com"

The structure above reflects the js object returned from Firebase.  What's the simplest js I can write to query the object structure above for all users with a last name of "Smith"?

*** UPDATE ***

I've revised my original question above to simplify it a bit. Here's some pseudocode if it helps clarify things at all:

var filtered = users.select(x => x.firstChild().LastName === 'Smith')

Comment: Can you show some code?  What ref objects do you have defined and available?

Comment: thanks doug - here's a screenshot of my cdt: https://www.dropbox.com/s/r9omk7hhc2d94ye/CDT.PNG?dl=0.  so if i have an email addr val, how can I use js to lookup the associated id?  represented in the example in this screenshot as either 1 or 2

Comment: That's not code, that's a dump of some logged objects.  Please edit your question showing the code that you need to modify to suit whatever requirements you have.

Comment: @Doug - the screenshot shows the js object array returned by snapshot.val().  does the screenshot of the object array not provide enough info on how the id can be queried ifony the email address is known?

Comment: An object val gives you nothing you can work with to find another location in the database.  You need to show code and say what you're having trouble with from there.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask